# How to run Apple Accelerate fft algorithms with data length, which is not power of 2?

Tags: ios, c, algorithm, accelerate-framework, vdsp

I want to port an algorithm from Android to iOS written in C. For Android I use fftw3 library. And it is able to run the algorithm on input data with any size. For example the size I see in debug is 14996. And It's pretty efficient. And when I read the docs from here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1449739-vdsp_dft_zrop_createsetup?language=objc I see that there are some spesific requirements for input length. Are there any way to avoid this or to modify the input data to meet the requirements?

Comment: If you don't have much to add to reach the `k x 2^n`, you could use the zero-padding technique (low distortion in this case), or interpolation. [This question on MO](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26432/discrete-fourier-transform-effects-of-zero-padding-compared-to-time-domain-inte) might be of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, no, the Accelerate DFT routines only support the documented sizes. Only powers of two multiplied by 1, 3, 5, or 15 are supported.

(These include sizes that have been useful previously. It is possible to support other sizes in the future if we get sufficient requests for them, but 14996 seems unusual. Usually numbers with only small prime factors are preferred, but 14996 has a factor of 151. What makes it a size that is interesting to take a DFT for?)

As for modifying your input data, some applications will pad their data with zeroes to make it a supported length. But then adjustments may need to be made, depending on the application.

You can, of course, also use FFTW on iOS.